# Java - Print document with dialog?

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe

How do I open up a print dialog box where you select your printer, page details, etc to print A SPECIFIED DOCUMENT OR JTEXTPANE?

Please help!

note: getDesktop().print gives me an error about printer setup, how to open the native print dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Lesson: Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) in Java tutorials, [Using Print Setup Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html) in particular. [PrinterJob.printDialog()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html#printDialog%28%29) should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

> An application displays a print dialog when the user presses a button related to the print command, or chooses an item from the print menu. To display this dialog, call the printDialog method of the PrinterJob class:

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
//...
    if (pj.printDialog()) {
        try {pj.print();}
        catch (PrinterException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
         }
     }   
//...
```

**Reference**:

- [Using Print Setup Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html)
- [Lesson: Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html)

Comment: So how do I specify WHAT to print?

Comment: @user1332495 Just follow the tutorial, everything is explained: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html